# Why does Chrome always redirect me to https://www.google.com

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https

Whenever I enter "http://www.google.de" (or any other google domain) in the addressbar, it is automatically replaced by "https://www.google.de".

This happens regardless of beeing logged in with my google account or not. 
There are some hints on the web, that this behaviour can be disabled, but unfortunately google changed something, and these options are not available anymore (see [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2011/10/23/google-redirects-your-search-to-https-change-it/))

In the network I am at the moment all SSL- traffic is directed over a "man-in-the-middle"- proxy, so that chrome will not let me open the https:// - links (certificate error).

that's why I want to disable this feature. Anyone who can help me with that?

Before I forget: Chrome version is 27.0.1453.110

EDIT: This has NOTHING to do with the omnibox- search... Chrome just rewrites any google- url I enter...

Comment: Network admins and their silly attempt to implement security protecting domain resources from promiscuous surfers sure can be frustrating for those users who don't want to play by the rules...

Comment: you are so true... Problem is: In this constellation I can not use google to search in chrome at all... I cannot use http:// as chrome redirects and i cannot use https:// due to the proxy... right now I search google with IE...

Comment: Does this only happen with Chrome?

Comment: Yes, IE does not do this

Comment: have you tried Firefox? I've found it has many more config options than Chrome, especially if you use `about:config` as a URI.

Comment: That was not my question... Yes I could use another browser, it works with them.. My question was related to using Chrome...

Comment: This may or may not help you, but: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/873?hl=en

Comment: I would say that, if there's a man-in-the-middle issue for HTTPS, it's almost certainly there for HTTP as well. Why would someone only want to monitor HTTPS and not HTTP? It's just that HTTP has no way to inform you. Thus you'd be no worse off forcing Chrome to temporarily allow the bad certificate. Just avoid doing anything that actually needs to be kept secure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's because their web servers send the HSTS header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

Comment: This sound exactly like the behavior I see... I will check, if I can let chrome ignore hsts- requests...

Comment: You're somewhat right. Note that Chrome has list of HSTS-enabled domains pre-loaded by default. No need to send separate header for them. Source: http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json?view=markup

Comment: The additional comment of Ilya Zakreuski proved: Yes, this is the reason for redirection, and there seems no way, to disable it. SO this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the identical behavior in my Chrome installation.

I inspected the process by opening the Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>), switching to the **Network** tab and opening `http://google.de`.

At first, I get redirected to `http://www.google.de` and then I get a 302 reply that redirects me to `https://www.google.de`. So the behavior is determined server-side.

[image]

However, in my case there is a difference between being logged in or not (when logged into Google, I get redirected. When not logged in, I don't).

Given that the behavior is controlled server-side, I would suspect some cookie to be the reason for this. Try the same procedure in an Incognito tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>) and maybe clear your cookies.